# onsen.io angular 1.x custom animation broken going from 2.6.2 -> 2.9.2

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

Tried to ask this question in your FORUM on `onsen.io` but your `NEW TOPIC` button is broken - even when i am logged in - the button does nothing - doesnt even throw an error.... so here we are

i recently upgraded onsen.io so i can have iPhone-X compatibility.

now my custom animation is broken

`dropAnimation.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NavigatorTransitionAnimator' of undefined at dropAnimation.js:15`

and here is the code that used to work (and which the onsen guy helped me perfect it)

```
// register custom lift animation
var dropAnimator = function(options) {
  options = options || {};

  this.timing = options.timing || 'ease';
  this.duration = options.duration || 0.4;
  this.delay = options.delay || 0;

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; background-color: black; opacity: 0;"></div>';
  this.backgroundMask = div.firstChild;
  this.blackMaskOpacity = 0.4;
};

dropAnimator.prototype = Object.create(ons.NavigatorElement.NavigatorTransitionAnimator.prototype);

dropAnimator.prototype.push = function(enterPage, leavePage, callback) {
    this.backgroundMask.remove();
    leavePage.parentNode.insertBefore(this.backgroundMask, leavePage);

    ons.animit.runAll(
        ons.animit(enterPage)
          .saveStyle()
          .queue({
            css: {
              transform: 'translate3D(0px, -100%, 0px)',
              opacity: 0.9
            },
            duration: 0
          })
          .wait(this.delay)
          .queue({
            css: {
              transform: 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)',
              opacity: 1.0
            },
            duration: this.duration,
            timing: this.timing
          })
          .restoreStyle()
          .queue(function(done) {
            this.backgroundMask.remove();
            callback();
            done();
          }.bind(this))

    );
};

dropAnimator.prototype.pop = function(enterPage, leavePage, callback) {
    this.backgroundMask.remove();
    enterPage.parentNode.insertBefore(this.backgroundMask, enterPage);

    ons.animit.runAll(
        ons.animit(leavePage)
          .queue({
            css: {
              transform: 'translate3D(0px, 0px, 0px)'
            },
            duration: 0
          })
          .wait(this.delay)
          .queue({
            css: {
              transform: 'translate3D(0px, -100%, 0px)'
            },
            duration: this.duration,
            timing: this.timing
          })
          .queue(function(done) {
            this.backgroundMask.remove();
            callback();
            done();
          }.bind(this))
    );
};

// register animation name
ons.NavigatorElement.registerAnimator('drop', dropAnimator);
```

this is a simple lift and drop animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name spaces have simply changed - making this adjustment registers the animation properly.

```
dropAnimator.prototype = Object.create(ons.elements.Navigator.NavigatorAnimator.prototype);

...

ons.elements.Navigator.registerAnimator('drop', dropAnimator);
```